# Can I modify a list view query for RailsAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In a RailsAdmin list view, I want to show a value that comes from an associated model. Eg, in a list of airports, I want to show the name of that airport's city. This works:

```
config.model 'Airport' do
  list do
    field :city_name do
      def value
        airport = bindings[:object]
        airport.city.name
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, it results in an N+1 query, as each airport object generates a query to find its city. I'd like to make it so that the query that finds airports joins the cities table.

**Does RailsAdmin let me modify the query scope used to find objects for the list view?**